# Using local helper to get thumbnails in minicart

Tags: magento-1.9, php, ce-1.9.0.1, thumbnail, mini-cart

This is my code that imports the images from the server

```
<?php
 class Bundle_LocalHelpers_Helper_Basic extends Mage_core_Helper_Abstract {

   public function getImageUrl($product)
{

   $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
   $sku = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($product->getId(), 'sku', $storeId);

    $asin = substr($sku,0,10);

    if ($sku != null) {

        return "http://productimages.shop.com/images/$asin.jpg";
    }
    else
    {
        return "http://productimages.shop.com/images/$sku.jpg";
    }
 }
 }
```

And from this I am trying to include them in minicart/default.phtml to get the thumbnails however when I try to add the localhelper class the php crashes.

This is the code for the default.phtml

```
    <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl()?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $localHelper->getImageUrl($product)->resize(50, 50)->setWatermarkSize('30x10'); ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" /></a>
<?php else: ?>
    <span class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(50, 50)->setWatermarkSize('30x10'); ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" /></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any suggestions how to add it ?

Comment: What is inside $localHelper?

Comment: The first code displays the local helper class

Comment: That doesn’t answer my question. Where is the $localHelper initialized?

Comment: Top of the default.phtml /**
 * @var Bundle_LocalHelpers_Helper_Basic $localHelper
 */
 $localHelper = Mage::helper('localhelper/basic');
?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right answer:

```
 <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl()?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $localHelper->getImageUrl($_item->getProduct());/*echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(50, 50)->setWatermarkSize('30x10');*/ ?>" width="50" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" /></a>
```

Instead of using

`$localHelper->getImageUrl($product)`

you have to use

```
$localHelper->getImageUrl($_item->getProduct())
```

Thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but I think problem is in resize which you are using. try to remove that. Resize will not work with your third party custom image URL.

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl()?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $localHelper->getImageUrl($product); ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" /></a>
```

Comment: throws php error and doesn't display main content or footer as it is php error.

Comment: what error it is showing ?

Comment: No error , the page basically crashes , and when i try to click on the minicart it doesn't display its content.

Comment: Do you have any live URL? Or try to echo  $asin in your code and see what value it is showing and that jpg file is exist in your server or not

Comment: I'm already using this helper class once in my slider on home page and the pictures are there I'm using <img  class="lazyOwl" src="<?php echo $localHelper->getImageUrl($product); ?>" alt="img" /> and it displays the images for products.

Comment: okay, so it must be some other conflict. need to debug that is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Mage::helper('localHelpers/basic')->getImageUrl($product)` in minicart/default.phtml wherever you want to display the image.